# How to map an array after making changes to it in react js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm mapping an array and each has a button to delete it from the array :

```
const comments = [ 'Hey', 'Yo' ];

            {comments.map((each, index) => {
                return (
                    <div key={index}>
                        <button
                            onClick={() => {
                                console.log(comments.indexOf(each));
                                const id = comments.indexOf(each);
                                comments.splice(id, 1);
                                console.log(comments);
                            }}
                        >
                            Button
                        </button>
                    </div>);
            }
```

When the button is clicked the item will be deleted and It console logs the array after deleting it and it works fine .

```
1
App.js:17 ["Hey"]
App.js:14 0
App.js:17 []
```

The only problem is the array which is displayed on the screen doesn't update in other words array displayed on the screen doesn't change after clicking the button and it still shows the whole array which has all the items .

How can I map through the changed version of the array or what am I doing wrong with mapping an array that doesn't display the changed version of it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have to use [useState](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const [comments, setComments ] = useState([ 'Hey', 'Yo' ]);
```

and inside your onClick function:

```
setComments(comments.filter((comment, index)=>index!==id));
```

I used [.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) because your use of splice will return the cutted element of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Assign the updated array to the real array like this. and change the type of comments to `var`. `const` cant be updated.

```
comments = comments.splice(id, 1);
```

If you want to rerender after deletion, you can use state variables and `setState` on deletion.

In the constructor of component initialize the comments variable

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {comments: ['A', 'B']};
  }
```

Then on click of delete button update the state

```
this.setState({
      comments: comments.splice(id, 1);
    });
```

Comment: I don't think that will help. The problem is that the component won't re-render. The proper solution would be to use `useState` for the comments.

Comment: In any case you have to update the original array or state variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using React Hooks in your project may simply use the useState() then you could simply set the values.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the point in how React internally works. React will rerender the component based on props or state change.

You are not using the React state here, which would then cause the component to render again with new value of the state.

Simply put comments in state like this
`const [comments, setComments] = useState([ 'Hey', 'Yo' ])`

and then assign new value of comments in your callback with `setComments`